# stubbing a nested private async function with powermock

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I have a function with the following flow:

```
public static void func(
      ClassA a, ClassB b) {
    a.innerfunc().innerfunc().addListener(
            new Listener<IUser>() {

              @Override
              public void onDataReceived(IUser response) {
                mAttrDict = response.toDict();
              }

              @Override
              public void onError(ErrorClass error) {
                a.getLogger()
                    .error("log-message");
              }
            };
  }
```

I would like to stub the addListener and send a custom dict for testing.
Is it somehow possible with powermock?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The use of <strike>PowerMock</strike> is almost ever a surrender to a bad design.

In your case it looks like your code violates "Information hiding/encapsulation" which leads to the *chain wracking" calls `a.innerfunc().innerfunc()`

You should transform you code so that the object needing to be mocked can be passed to your code under test as an *injected dependency* that can be created using vanilla Mockito.